# いろいろなところから呼び出せるUIAlertの作り方

Tags: ios, swift

UIAlertをいろいろなところから呼び出し可能にしたいと思っています。
例えば

```
MyAlert.show()
```

といった感じに。

下記のようなクラスを作って表示させるのは作法としておかしいでしょうか？
特にrootViewControllerを呼び出している辺りについてどうするのが適切でしょうか？

```
import UIKit

class MyAlert {

    class func show(){

        let alertTitle = "アラート"
        let alertMsg = "サンプルアラートです。"

        let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: alertMsg, preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "キャンセル", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
            //nothing
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let submitAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
            //something to do
        }
        alertController.addAction(submitAction)
        var rootvc = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
        rootvc!.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

わたしなりの考え方で、手を加えてみました。

```
import UIKit

class MyAlert {

    class func show(fromViewController viewController: UIViewController){

        let alertTitle = "アラート"
        let alertMsg = "サンプルアラートです。"

        let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: alertMsg, preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "キャンセル", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
            //nothing
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let submitAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
            //something to do
        }
        alertController.addAction(submitAction)

        viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

View Controllerの実装内で呼び出す場合は、

```
MyAlert.show(fromViewController: self)
```

このように引数にselfを渡します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはりviewcontrollerを使う側から渡す方法が安定的に利用しやすそうですので、この方法を元にしたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

ただ rootViewController に present させる構造では、rootViewController が既に別のビューコントローラをモーダル表示している状態で期待通りに動作しないと思います。

keyWindow が正しく指定されていることが前提ですが、以下のように最前面のビューコントローラを取得して、それに present させる必要があるのではないでしょうか。

```
let keyWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
var frontViewController: UIViewController = keyWindow.rootViewController as UIViewController!
while frontViewController.presentedViewController != nil {
  frontViewController = frontViewController.presentedViewController!
}

frontViewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。仰るとおりモーダルの状態ではエラーとなりました。この方法ですとやはりループになることがあるので、viewcontrollerを渡す方法を取りたいと思います。